# Invalid File Name on login to SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle-11g, sqlplus, errors

The moment I log into SQLPLUS I get an `SP2-0556` error. I recently moved OS but am connecting to the same database so I am not sure if it's because I'm using my old TNSNames or what. I can connect and work normally but a few issues have arisen with running SQL scripts due to this where they then say `Invalid File Name`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

- the database is 11g,
- the command I use for running scripts is a custom ant script that basically loops through and runs normal .sql scripts,
- and I changed from a Ubuntu system to Mac OS X.

The issues are that any new scripts I create (that I know work) give a `Invalid File Name` error then stop.

Comment: Is sqlplus aliased to anything? (Type "alias" from the shell to check). Once connected, if you reconnect without exiting SQL/PLUS (`connect user/pass`) & still get the error it's because there's a `login.sql`/`glogin.sql` script being executed.

Comment: I tried that Phil, alias shows nothing, and running the connect user/pass command I got TNS:NET service name is incorrectly specified, warning: you are no longer connected to ORACLE.

Comment: Sorry, do: connect user/pass@dbname

Comment: Given your edit, it's probably an ant config problem (passing the wrong script location path). Have you verified the ant config?

Comment: The connect user/pass@dbName does give me the same error again, the ant config is fine and it works on many other builds, as I said it's only one script that's failing out of hundreds, but I'm not sure how long this Invalid File Name has been appearing when loading up SQLPLUS as I imported it in as soon as I moved OS I'll look into my login.sql.

Comment: Cool, definitely login.sql then!

Answer (score 1):

This might be `Bug 7150873 SQL SCRIPTS FILE NAME CONTAINING SPACES RESULTS IN SP2-0556`.

I assume that your script is trying to call a script containing spaces.

Comment: I think your right, I rebuilt my database and ALL existing scripts that never used to cause any problems are now all throwing up SP2-0556 errors, however they are still compiling and working fine, which is very strange.